# Media Player pauses the music when the activity loses focus(when home or screen goes off)

Tags: java, android, android-mediaplayer

the mediaplayer stops music when homebutton is pressed or screen goes off....I want the music to continue even if the activity loses focus....but i want the music to pause for the incoming calls and if user pauses the music....also the music should stop when the activity is closed via the back button

here's sample of my code:

```
package com.example.acer.aartisangrah;

import android.content.Context;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.telephony.PhoneStateListener;
import android.telephony.TelephonyManager;
import android.text.Html;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.SeekBar;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class ekdanta extends AppCompatActivity implements Runnable, View.OnClickListener,SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener {
TextView tv4;
Button b9, b10,but19;
int count = 0;
MediaPlayer play;
SeekBar seek_bar;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_ekdanta);
    tv4 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView9);
    tv4.setTextSize(18);
    tv4.setText(Html.fromHtml(getString(R.string.thirteen)));
    b9 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.b9);
    b10 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.b10);
    seek_bar = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.seekBar);
    seek_bar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(this);
    seek_bar.setEnabled(false);
    but19 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button19);
    but19.setOnClickListener(this);
    TelephonyManager mTelephonyManager = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
    mTelephonyManager.listen(mPhoneListener, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE);
}
private final PhoneStateListener mPhoneListener=new PhoneStateListener(){
    public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber) {
        super.onCallStateChanged(state, incomingNumber);

        // Call receive state
        if (state != TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE) {
            if ((play!= null) && (play.isPlaying()))
            {
                play.pause();
                but19.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.play);
            }
        }
    }
};

public void run() {
    int currentPosition = play.getCurrentPosition();
    final int total = play.getDuration();
    while (play != null && currentPosition < total) {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
            currentPosition = play.getCurrentPosition();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            return;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return;
        }
        seek_bar.setProgress(currentPosition);
    }
}
public void onClick(View v) {
    if (v.equals(but19)) {
        if (play == null) {
            play = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), R.raw.ekadanta);
            seek_bar.setEnabled(true);
        }
        if (play.isPlaying()) {
            play.pause();
            but19.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.play);
        } else {
            play.start();
            but19.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.pause);
            seek_bar.setMax(play.getDuration());
            new Thread(this).start();
        }
    }
    play.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
            play.seekTo(0);
            but19.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.play);
        }
    });
}

@Override
protected void onPause()
{
    super.onPause();
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy()
{
    super.onDestroy();
    play.release();
}

@Override
public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seek_bar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
    try{
        if(play.isPlaying()||play!=null){
            if (fromUser)
                play.seekTo(progress);
        }
        else if(play==null){
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"First Play", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            seek_bar.setProgress(0);
        }
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        Log.e("seek bar",""+e);
        seek_bar.setEnabled(false);
    }
}

@Override
public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

}

@Override
public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

}

public void increase(View inc) {
    count++;
    if (count == 1) {
        tv4.setTextSize(22);
    } else if (count == 2) {
        tv4.setTextSize(30);
    } else if (count >= 3) {
        count = 3;
        tv4.setTextSize(40);
    }
}

public void decrease(View dec) {
    count--;
    if (count <= 0) {
        tv4.setTextSize(18);
        count = 0;
    }
    if (count == 1) {
        tv4.setTextSize(22);
    } else if (count == 2) {
        tv4.setTextSize(30);
    } else if (count == 3) {
        tv4.setTextSize(40);
    }
}
}
```

**EDIT**

After using this code for the activity...this activity does not get opened on some devices...the app just closes itself....Please Help!!!
Other activities without this code works just fine...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To stop pausing of music when app gets to background. Comment `play.pause()` as below:

```
@Override 
protected void onPause() 
{ 
    super.onPause(); 
    if ((play!= null) && (play.isPlaying())) 
    { 
        // play.pause(); 
    } 
}
```

The playback should itself stop it on back press (I'm almost certain). Make sure you dispose off the mediaPlayer in `onDestroy()`.

To stop it on call receive. Instantiate the following receiver in your activity:

```
// Listens for phone state and pauses in an event of call
    private final PhoneStateListener mPhoneListener = new PhoneStateListener() {
        public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber) {
            super.onCallStateChanged(state, incomingNumber);

            // Call receive state
            if (state != TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE) {
                if ((play!= null) && (play.isPlaying())) 
                { 
                    play.pause(); 
                }
            }
        }
    };
```

You need to register for it as (probably in `onCreate()`):

```
// Make mTelephonyManager an instance variable
TelephonyManager mTelephonyManager = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
mTelephonyManager.listen(mPhoneListener, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE);
```

Don't forget to unregister it in `onDestroy()`:

```
mTelephonyManager.listen(mPhoneListener, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_NONE);
```

Comment: This works the way I wanted but the problem is when the music is playing in the backgroung and the user opens the app from the launcher the app restarts and when clicked play new music starts over it(this problem is not caused if the app is opened from the recent apps)

Comment: @Devk Ok..does the music simply starts from the beginning or does the music plays over the previously playing music [together with it]?

Comment: The music plays over the previoulsy playing music

Comment: You are stopping the music in `onDestroy()`, right?

Comment: Its like if I'm playing the music and press the home button and now if i open the app from the launcher....the app loads from the beggining and playing the music again causes it to play over the already playing music....

Comment: i have put the whole activity

Comment: Do any of the activities have a 'launchMode' property set in the manifest?

Comment: @Devk probably because as per your code above your are defining `mTelephonyManager` in `onCreate()`...Like I said, define it as an instance variable like your mediaplayer.

Comment: @Shaishav.....this activity doesnt get opened on some devices like redmi note 3.....after clicking on this activity....the app directly closes....help plz

Comment: @Shaishav....if I open the activity and close it without playing the music...the app force closes...

Comment: @Devk Its really difficult to diagnose issues like these without looking at the ENTIRE app flow or at the very least a logcat

Comment: Everything solved!!!! I dint set permission in the manifest file....thanks for the help!!!!

Comment: @Devk cool!... If you feel satisfied, mark the issue as resolved.

Answer (score 5):

First of all, you have the following code

```
@Override
protected void onPause()
{
    super.onPause();
    if ((play!= null) && (play.isPlaying()))
    {
        play.pause();
    }
}
```

onPause method is executed every time the activity goes to background (loses focus) or when it is closed by the user. So your first step would be to remove this code from the onPause method, where you deliberately call `play.pause()`.

You should overwrite the `onBackPressed()` method and do something similar to what you are doing but calling `play.stop()`

Check [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/mediaplayer.html), specifically on the **Performing cleanup** section where it says the following

> a MediaPlayer object can consume a significant amount of system
> resources, so you should keep it only for as long as you need and call
> release() when you are done with it. It's important to call this
> cleanup method explicitly rather than rely on system garbage
> collection because it might take some time before the garbage
> collector reclaims the MediaPlayer

Make sure to take a look at that guide as well.

Comment: Hey, I was thinking that as soon as `super.onBackPressed()` is called `finish()` will follow soon after. So, the mediaPlayer instance will also get destroyed (garbage collected eventually as long as its reference is not held by any other external class). So, I don't we need to stop it in `onBackPressed()`.

Comment: Yes you are right, it will be garbage collected eventually, but it is recommended as good practice, to release the media player when you for sure are done using it. Check my updated answer :)

Comment: Yeah..I usually put that cleanup code at the very least in `onDestroy()` if not in `onPause()` (depends on the use case) :)...

Comment: @LeandroTemperoni...this activity doesnt get opened on some devices(redmi note 3)....the app just closes itself after clicking on the activity.....